# How can I compute this accuracy without looping each elements of data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use a for loop to compute an accuracy between y_pred and y_true, this make my code very slow so I want to avoid this for loop. How can I change this code?

```
sumAcc =  tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
for i in range(0, y_pred_batch_size):
    ele_y_pred = y_pred[i, 0:label_length[i,0]]
    ele_y_true = y_true[i, 0:label_length[i,0]]
    sumAcc =  sumAcc + tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal( ele_y_pred, ele_y_true), tf.float32)) 
tf.print("\n","Accuracy: ",sumAcc / tf.constant(y_pred_batch_size,dtype=tf.float32) * 100,"%" )
```

The values of y_pred and y_true look like.. `[batch_index, [[45],[56],[12],...]`

Comment: What kind of accuracy are you trying to measure. Do all values in a batch index need to match for it to count as equal?

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example of what you're trying to do?